# Find most recent data per day

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Hey guys I have a database that is updated every few hours but I'm having a hard time trying to query the most recent data from each day from a date range.

My database structure looks like this

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b96787ebe9d44528eaa18a0"),
        "values" : [{}],
        "user": "user10",
        "date" : "2018-09-09 00:00:00",
        "type" : "patient",
        "extracted_date" : "2018-09-10 10:58:18"
}
```

I was able to get close to the behaivor that I want by grouping date and getting the last extracted date, like this:

```
{ "_id" : "2018-09-15 00:00:00", "extracted_date" : "2018-09-19 13:50:22" }
{ "_id" : "2018-09-16 00:00:00", "extracted_date" : "2018-09-19 13:47:26" }
{ "_id" : "2018-09-17 00:00:00", "extracted_date" : "2018-09-19 13:45:00" }
{ "_id" : "2018-09-11 00:00:00", "extracted_date" : "2018-09-12 10:09:17" }
{ "_id" : "2018-09-12 00:00:00", "extracted_date" : "2018-09-14 15:34:59" }
{ "_id" : "2018-09-14 00:00:00", "extracted_date" : "2018-09-19 13:54:34" }
{ "_id" : "2018-09-13 00:00:00", "extracted_date" : "2018-09-14 15:36:10" }
{ "_id" : "2018-09-18 00:00:00", "extracted_date" : "2018-09-19 13:42:23" }
```

But when I group the data I end up getting all the values from that day and I only need the last one. Here's an example of the query I used:

```
db.collection.aggregate({'$match': {'type': 'user', 'date': {'$gte': '2018-09-11 00:00:00', '$lte': '2018-09-18 00:00:00'}}}, {'$group': {'_id': {'type': '$type', 'user': '$user', 'date': '$date'}, 'extracted_date': {'$last': '$extracted_date'}, 'values': {'$push': '$values'}}})
```

If possile I would like to retrive the information as close to the structure utilized by the database.

Thank you very much for your help!

Edit: This is a case example that I need.

database objects:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b96787ebe9d44528eaa18a0"),
        "values" : [{'field1': 1, 'field2': 3}],
        "user": "user10",
        "date" : "2018-09-09 00:00:00",
        "type" : "patient",
        "extracted_date" : "2018-09-10 10:58:18"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b96787ebe9d44528eaa18a0"),
        "values" : [{'field1': 1, 'field2': 4}],
        "user": "user10",
        "date" : "2018-09-09 00:00:00",
        "type" : "patient",
        "extracted_date" : "2018-09-11 10:58:18"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b96787ebe9d44528eaa18a0"),
        "values" : [{'field11': 2, 'field2': 10}],
        "user": "user11",
        "date" : "2018-09-05 00:00:00",
        "type" : "patient",
        "extracted_date" : "2018-09-10 10:58:18"
}
```

Expected return:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b96787ebe9d44528eaa18a0"),
        "values" : [{'field1': 1, 'field2': 4}],
        "user": "user10",
        "date" : "2018-09-09 00:00:00",
        "type" : "patient",
        "extracted_date" : "2018-09-11 10:58:18"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b96787ebe9d44528eaa18a0"),
        "values" : [{'field11': 2, 'field2': 10}],
        "user": "user11",
        "date" : "2018-09-05 00:00:00",
        "type" : "patient",
        "extracted_date" : "2018-09-10 10:58:18"
}
```

Since there's 2 objected from the same date it only returns the one with the most recent extracted_date

Comment: Can you provide more details on what you mean by `last one`? Is it just the last one from the `values` or you want to last sorted by date etc?

Comment: I need the most recent data from eachday between the date range passed in the query. 
I edited the question with an example

Comment: I updated my answer. @matthPen was correct with his suggestion to `sort` after the initial match since otherwise we have hard time getting the most recent `values`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to just get the `last` `values` array and not all of them for that day combined ...

So just do `$last` for the values like you did for `extracted_date`.

**UPDATE**:

Since you are looking for the most recent data for that range you need to use the `sort` as per `matthPen` suggestion and just get the needed fields out of the `_id` and then hide the `_id`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    "$match": {
      "type": "patient",
      "date": {
        "$gte": "2018-09-05 00:00:00",
        "$lte": "2018-09-18 00:00:00"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "extracted_date": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "type": "$type",
        "user": "$user",
        "date": "$date"
      },
      "id": {
        $last: "$_id"
      },
      "date": {
        $last: "$date"
      },
      "type": {
        $last: "$type"
      },
      "extracted_date": {
        $last: "$extracted_date"
      },
      "values": {
        $last: "$values"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0
    }
  }
])
```

You can see it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MJHTbZxMwz7)

Comment: Downvote because $last take only the last coming from previous stage in pipeline, no comparison is applied!  Check the result on your playground, it's not the one expected!

Comment: The question asked was about the `values` not about the `expected_date` sorting. I quote "I end up getting all the values from that day and I only need the last one". 

You seem to be very trigger happy with your downvotes.

Comment: And how do you retrieve the last value? What is 'last' value for you? check your mongo playgroud result, it returns value for extracted date "2018-09-10 10:48:18", which is in fact the last document in your collection, not the last for the day! You seem misunderstanding the question...

Comment: I made up that sample data since there is no such from the OP. `last` in this case means that instead of the result containing the 3 values it only contains the last one which as you can see form the mongo playground is exactly that ... `{"c":1}`

Comment: After the OP added more information I agree with you and your suggestion to sort after the initial match. I updated my answer to match the OP desired output etc.

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you very much for the help! =)

Answer (score 0):

Think you are confusing between 'the last per day' (the one which appened the later in each day) and $last (the last coming from previous stage in pipeline)!

You need to add a sort stage before grouping, to ensure that $last is 'the last'.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$match": {
    "type": "user",
    "date": {
      "$gte": "2018-09-11 00:00:00",
      "$lte": "2018-09-18 00:00:00"
    }
  }
}, 
{$sort:{
  date:1,
  extracted_date:1
}
},
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "type": "$type",
      "user": "$user",
      "date": "$date"
    },
    "extracted_date": {
      "$last": "$extracted_date"
    },
    "values": {
      "$last": "$values"
    }
  }
})
```